# How to add customer details in change email template in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, email, email-templates, change

How to add the customer email in **"change email address template"** in magento 2.3

> **Config :** Stores -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Account Information Options -> Change Email Template  (Default Config)

**Email Template :**

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<p class="greeting">{{trans "Hello,"}}</p>
<br>

<p>
    {{trans "We have received a request to change the following information associated with your account at %store_name: email." store_name=$store.frontend_name}}
    {{trans 'If you have not authorized this action, please contact us immediately at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email |raw}}{{depend store_phone}} {{trans 'or call us at <a href="tel:%store_phone">%store_phone</a>' store_phone=$store_phone |raw}}{{/depend}}.
</p>
<br>

<p>{{trans "Thanks,<br>%store_name" store_name=$store.frontend_name |raw}}</p>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

**Output now :**

```
Hello,

We have received a request to change the following information associated with your account at My Store: email. If you have not authorized this action, please contact us immediately at example@test.com.

Thanks,
Main Web Store
```

**Expected Result :**

```
Hello,

We have received a request to change the following information associated with your account at My Store: email **"Customer Email"**. If you have not authorized this action, please contact us immediately at example@test.com.

Thanks,
Main Web Store
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the existing current `customer` template variable same as the store you can find the function `getFullCustomerObject` in the file: `vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/EmailNotification.php` in this method data are already passing you can modify it as per your preference.

You can refer the `emailChanged` function in the same file where it call the `sendEmailTemplate` function and it has the `$templateParams` params in the 4th Arguments.

So in the template, you can use the variable **$customer**

```html
{{trans 'If you have not authorized this action, please contact us immediately at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%customer_email</a>' customer_email=$customer.email |raw}}
```